# Setting a property from the Pylons .ini file

Tags: python, configuration, pylons

Let's say I have a `settings.py` file in my app's root folder (`/myapp/myapp/settings.py`) with just a bunch of variables in it:

```
var1 = ''
var2 = ''
```

Can I automatically set one of those variables from the `.ini` file? I tried this:

```
myapp.settings.var1 = 'this is from development.ini'
```

But when I call `var1` it is still the empty string:

```
import myapp.settings as s
print s.var1
```

I know that I can do `var1 = config.get('myapp.settings.var1')` in `settings.py` but that just doesn't seem as elegant to me :).

Answer (score 1):

You can find relevant information at this page:

[Getting Data from the Configuration File](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Getting+Data+from+the+Configuration+File)

Answer (score 0):

`.ini` is **one way only** communication. **Django** uses **settings.py** which is a normal python module that can be manipulated on-the-fly (causing many obscure errors). Setup your settings in `.ini` and use `config.get` to access variables.

Comment: Django? Did you mean Pylons? I'm not using Django here.

Comment: Pylons doesn't use settings.py.